# Java DOM/AST - why is MethodInvocation an Expression?

Tags: java, dom, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

In the Java DOM/AST (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/package-tree.html) why does an Initializer contain a Block and why is a MethodInvocation an Expression and not a Statement?

I mean, given the code

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

the ASTView plugin shows me only INITIALIZER > MethodInvocation
Can there ever be an Initializer that really has a Block element?

Moreover, if I have a method like this

```
public void thisMethod(){
    System.out.println();
}
```

MethodInvocation is wrapped into an ExpressionStatement. But why isn't MethodInvocation a Statement? Just a simple System.out.println() is a valid "Statement". An Expression in the sense of the Java DOM/AST lacks the ability to stand for itself.

Maybe I just didn't the get the whole idea of the separation between Expression and Statement.

Comment: this "RTFM" didnt help me at all, sorry. Moreover, it didn't answer the first question

Comment: Well, do you understand the concept of expression and statements? If not, there’s no sense of asking about the reasoning of a particular implementation. Regarding your first question, “why does an Initializer contain a Block”— I don’t get it, what else should an Intializer contain if not a Block?

Comment: and your link helps to clearify? No, it doesn't. An Expression cannot stand for itself, a Statement can. But a MethodInvocation CAN stand for itself! "If not a block": a single Expression

Comment: But a method invocation can return a value and hence it is allowed where an expression is allowed. A method invocation fits *both* expression *and* statement. That’s the point of Expression Statements and, yes, the link explains it. But you have to read more than just the few sentences at the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AST tree is designed to reflect the syntax rules of the programming language.

Syntactically, an Initializer consists of a block with an optional `static` modifier before it. So it’s the most natural implementation having an `Initializer` class consisting of a `Block` and modifiers (inherited from `BodyDeclaration`). So I don’t understand why you question it.

Example of initializers:

```
class Foo {
  static {
    System.out.println("static initializer");
    System.out.println("class Foo now initialized");
  }

  {
    System.out.println("instance initializer");
    System.out.println("an instance of Foo has been created");
  }
}
```

---

Expressions and statements are two different syntactic constructs. There are places where only either an expression or a statement is allowed. But there are constructs like method invocations which are *Expression Statements* which means the can fulfill both roles, Expression and Statement. They can be invoked stand-alone for their side-effects but also at places where a value is required.

But since Java does not allow multiple inheritance you cannot create an AST class `ExpressionStatement` inheriting from both `Expression` and `Statement`. So you need a solution like in the Eclipse AST where `ExpressionStatement` inherits from one and wraps the other. The decision which one to inherit and which one to wrap is easy: you can create a `Statement` implementation (subclass) which drops the result of the `Expression` it has wrapped but you cannot create an `Expression` implementation which provides a result for a `Statement` that provides no result through its interface. An alternative to such an implementation would be the use of interfaces.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I now got why MI is an expression. But a Block looks like this { ... } . Have you ever seen an initialization like int a = { ... } ? For arrays, there is an ArrayInitializer. Afaik there is no Initializer that consists of more than one Statement (which is the function of a Block: to group several Statements)